# Credit and Debit

Tags: credit, accounting

I often get confused between debit and credit accounts for example.

Capital To Start Up Your Business , the two accounts being affected are bank and owner's equity ( if I'm correct that's why it's confusing for me ). Does your owner's equity get credited or debited? For me I personally think the bank is credit because it's receiving money. But then the owner's equity increases?

I'm still a bit new to this type of accounting.

Answer (score 0):

In view of business, we have to book the entries.
Business view, owner and business are different.
When capital is invested in business by owner, in future business has to repay it. 
That's why, capital always credit.

When we come about  bank (business prospective) - cash, bank, fd are like assets which can help in the business.
Bank is current asset (Real account) -
Debit (what comes into the business)
                                       Credit (what goes out of the business)

Hence credit and debit differs from what type of account is it....
credit - when business liables
debit - what business has and receivables

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand the concept, so I'll break it down as best as I can. 
There are three parts to the accounting equation:

> Assets = Liabilities + Owner's Equity

We'll look at this in two ways

1. View from business to bank
2. View from bank to business

---

1. As a business owner you invest (say) 10,000 USD into your bank. The entry would be:

> Debit: Assets: Cash for 10,000
>   
>  Credit: Owner's Equity: Contributions for 10,000

In this case, you have assets of 10,000 from your deposit, but it is due to owner contributions and not business transactions. Another example (say a sale):

> Debit: Assets: Cash for 10,000
>   
>  Credit: Owner's Equity: Sales for 10,000

---

2. From the bank's perspective, you are loaning money to them.

> Debit: Assets: Cash for 10,000
>   
>  Credit: Liabilities: Deposits for 10,000

Deposits are a banking term to reflect a bank's obligation to return the amount on demand (though the bank has free reign with it, see [fractional banking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional-reserve_banking))

---

You will NEVER debit or credit your bank as it is assumed you will be storing your money there, note [bank reconciliation](http://www.accountingtools.com/bank-reconciliation-procedure).

Hope this helps, comment with any more questions.